# return complement of a list of incidence binary vectors

Tags: python, list

i have to solve this excercise:

**Can you implement the function AND that takes as argument two incidence vectors (represented a binary lists in Python) and returns the complement of the two?**

es AND(1100,1110) = 1100

so i have this situation:

```
def AND(vector_a, vector_b):
    # insert your code here

# these tests should return True if your code is correct
print(AND([1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]) == [1, 1, 0, 0])
print(AND([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]) == [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

my solution was this:

```
def AND(va,vb):
    lista = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(va):
        if va[i] == 1 and vb[i]==1:
            lista.append(1)
        else:
            lista.append(0)
        i += 1
    return lista
```

that seems works, but now for the next excercise i have some problems:

**Rewrite the function AND to allow it to take an arbitary number of incidence vectors.**

```
def AND(*vectors):
    # insert your code here    

# these tests should return True if your code is correct
print(AND([1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]) == [1, 0, 0, 0])
print(AND([1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]) == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

can you help me to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can generalize what you have done so far:

```
def AND(*vectors):
    lista = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(vectors[0]):
        # add a temporary variable to check
        # if all i elements are ones 
        all_ones = True
        for v in vectors:
            all_ones = all_ones and v[i] == 1
        if all_ones:
            lista.append(1)
        else:
            lista.append(0)
        i += 1
    return lista
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) for these operations. Therefore you can do this with any number of lists.

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1]
b = [0, 1, 1, 1]
c = [0, 0, 0, 1]

results = []
for val in zip(a, b, c):
    results.append(int(all(val)))

print results
```

Basically what `zip` does is, it zips the elements of the lists according to their indexes(columns), you may think it as a matrix transpose.

So zipped version of a, b, c would be,

```
(1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

All the values you need to process are packed in tuples. Then you use `all` to apply `and` operation with these items, basically `all` checks if all of the elements of a container are `1`, if there is even a single `0`, it returns `false`, therefore `and` is satisfied.

This returns,

```
False
False
False
True
```

But you need integer values so `int(all(val))`,

```
0
0
0
1
```

For more information about `any` and `all`:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean solution, hiding all looping in list comprehensions and generator expressions:

```
def AND(*vectors):
    N = len(vectors[0])  # Get the length of the vectors
    return [int(all(vec[i] for vec  in vectors)) for i in range(N)]
```

The `all` function checks that all vectors have a 1 (or anything but 0, really) as the `i`th element. This returns either `True` or `False`. We can convert this to `1` or `0` by using the `int` function.